# MongoDB error reporting

Tags: php, mongodb, error-handling

After a save operation (`$col->save($w);`) an exception occur. But I just get following:

```
Fatal error: in D:\......\x.php on line 41
MongoException: in D:\......\x.php on line 41
```

How to get a more informative error message? Is there any config to enable error reporting for MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

To check out what errors you are getting, you can check the error codes you are getting when exception is raised. Check out the error code [here at PHP driver for mongo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoexception.php)

Answer (score 0):

To check if there was an error on the most recent db operation performed, you can use `MongoDB::lastError`.

```
var_dump($db->lastError());
```

---

**For your information**

If you run with driver version 1.3.0, `new Mongo` has been **DEPRECATED**. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. Please use `MongoClient` instead.